# Remove users from "All People" via SPO PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Is it possible to remove a user from the "All People" hidden group in SharePoint Online? Ideally via PowerShell if possible...

Currently you are able to view and manually delete users from a site collection via https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0. It would be great if anyone knew how to achieve this via PowerShell.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that you really want to do that? It might be an easy fix on a current issue, but long term it might really be a royal pain that all people is not all people.

Comment: Hi Kasper, thank you for your comments. Yes I am sure, removing the entry from the site collection All People group resolves an issue a user is experiencing (sharing error when inviting a user that has previously accessed our tenant). If the issue comes back I will contact Microsoft to take a look at the SPODS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following PowerShell to remove User from Site Collection in SharePoint online(change the parameters to your parameters):

```
#Parameters
$AdminSiteURL="https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/ops"
$UserID="zahia@crescent.com"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential

#Connect to SharePoint Online Admin Site
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL -Credential $cred

#Remove user from Site Collection
Remove-SPOUser -Site $SiteURL -LoginName $UserID
```

Reference:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/08/sharepoint-online-remove-user-from-site-collection-using-powershell.html

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/3026385/how-to-remove-users-from-sharepoint-online